# Display modal on valid select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to make a modal pop up when an option is selected in my dropdown list, however, I can't get it to refrain for working when the "default" option is selected (which has an empty value).

**My HTML**

```
<div class="dropdownPanel">
    <select name="countryList" id="countryList">
        <option value="" disabled selected>SELECT</option>
        <option value="argentinia">Argentinia</option>
        <option value="brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option value="chile">Chile</option>
        <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="venezuela">Venezuela</option>
    </select>
    <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
    <button class="confirm">confirm</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.dropdownPanel button.confirm').on('click', function() {
    if (!($('option[value=""]:selected'))) {
        $('.modal').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

I've also tried...

```
$('.dropdownPanel button.confirm').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#countryList option').val() > 0) {
        $('.modal').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/bbS8v/

**The Html**

```
<div class="dropdownPanel">
    <select name="countryList" id="countryList">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>SELECT</option>
        <option value="argentinia">Argentinia</option>
        <option value="brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option value="chile">Chile</option>
        <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="venezuela">Venezuela</option>
    </select>
    <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
    <button class="confirm">confirm</button>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.confirm').click( function() {
      var val = $("#countryList").val();
        if (val!=0) {
            $('.modal').show();
             // alert(val); //test
        }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: while this does work, i need the modal to only pop up when `.confirm` is clicked

Comment: nevermind, made a little edit and it works.  thanks for the help!

Comment: I made an edit that works as you required, not sure if same edit you made but check it as it may be of some help @BadDog

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.dropdownPanel button.confirm').on('click', function() {
      if (!($('option[value=""]:selected'))) {
        $('.modal').css('display', 'block');
      }
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: Change option[value=""]:selected to $("select[name=countryList]").val()